# Dependabot failing to update poetry TOML file for newer versions

Tags: github-actions, python-poetry, dependabot

For a couple of months now, the Dependabot update jobs are frequently failing if a newer version for a dependency is found. For items where no newer version is available, the job runs through successfully.

The following log extract is a good example of how the job fails:

```
updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 INFO <job_779935348> Updating pytest
from  to 8.0.0 updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 INFO <job_779935348>
[Transport] Sending envelope with items [event]
eafae4eb186c4620aae858b843c5ff36 to Sentry
updater | 2024/01/29
13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348> Error processing pytest (RuntimeError)
updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348> Content did not
change! updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/python/lib/dependabot/python/file_updater/poetry_file_updater.rb:74:in
`updated_pyproject_content' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR
<job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/python/lib/dependabot/python/file_updater/poetry_file_updater.rb:48:in
`fetch_updated_dependency_files' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR
<job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/python/lib/dependabot/python/file_updater/poetry_file_updater.rb:31:in
`updated_dependency_files' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR
<job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/python/lib/dependabot/python/file_updater.rb:101:in
`updated_poetry_based_files' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR
<job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/python/lib/dependabot/python/file_updater.rb:34:in
`updated_dependency_files' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR
<job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/dependency_change_builder.rb:91:in
`generate_dependency_files' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR
<job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/dependency_change_builder.rb:37:in
`run' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/dependency_change_builder.rb:26:in
`create_from' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/updater/operations/update_all_versions.rb:128:in
`check_and_create_pull_request' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR
<job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/updater/operations/update_all_versions.rb:60:in
`check_and_create_pr_with_error_handling' updater | 2024/01/29
13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/updater/operations/update_all_versions.rb:35:in
`block in perform' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/updater/operations/update_all_versions.rb:35:in
`each' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/updater/operations/update_all_versions.rb:35:in
`perform' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/updater.rb:45:in
`run' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/update_files_command.rb:43:in
`perform_job' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
/home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/base_command.rb:36:in
`run' updater | 2024/01/29 13:57:58 ERROR <job_779935348>
bin/update_files.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Maybe a bug report for [dependabot-core](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core)?

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW, openen issue in the corresponding repository: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/8931